# undefined reference to `llvm_gcov_init'

Tags: c, gcc, clang, code-coverage, gcov

Trying to compile a c project then encountered error like below

```
undefined reference to `__llvm_profile_instrument_target'
undefined reference to `llvm_gcda_start_file'
undefined reference to `llvm_gcov_init'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to using the wrong compiler! `gcov` is meants to be built with GCC. Therefore switching the compiler to GCC fixed the build

Answer (score 2):

It works with `llvm` compiler too, just add `--coverage`.

https://clang.llvm.org/docs/SourceBasedCodeCoverage.html

Comment: thanks for sharing, however doesn't have the code with me to try it out. will keep it for next time!